# An N-layer app deployed as a single unit is a monolith application?

Tags: architecture, distributed-system, n-tier-architecture

I have some questions about what exactly is considered a monolith application. It looks a controversial question and after reading about it I’m not able to find a definitive answers.

1. An application **not split into multiple layers** such as
   Presentation, Application, Business and Infrastructure layers that
   is **deployed as a single unit**, is considered a monolith
   application?
2. An **N-layer application split into multiple layers** such as
   Presentation, Application, Business and Infrastructure layers,
   **deployed as a single unit**, is also considered a monolith application?

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. If you can see your application as a series of autonomous systems with clear boundaries and that communicates with each other to form the bigger system then it is most likely not a monolith and vice-versa. The way a single service boundary is partitioned should not be taken into consideration.